# yargs warning: Too many arguments provided. Expected max 1 but received 2

Tags: node.js, yargs

I have an issue with my yargs configuration:

```
const argv = require('yargs')
    .boolean('reset', {
        alias: 'rs'
    })
    .boolean('refreshConfig', {
        alias: 'rc'
    })
    .option('harvest', {
        alias: 'h'
    })
    .option('lang', {
        alias: 'l',
        default: 'fr'
    })
    .help().argv;
```

I executed the script as below:

```
$ node ./srcjobs/cli.js --refreshConfig --harvest=facebook
```

and I received this error:

```
Too many arguments provided. Expected max 1 but received 2.
```

Do you know why ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.boolean` receive only 1 argument, from source code

```
boolean<K extends string>(key: K | ReadonlyArray<K>): Argv<T & { [key in K]: boolean | undefined }>;
```

Proper way

```
const argv = require('yargs')
  .boolean('reset')
  .alias('rs', 'reset')
  .boolean('refreshConfig')
  .alias('rc', 'refreshConfig')
  .option('harvest', {
    alias: 'h'
  })
  .option('lang', {
    alias: 'l',
    default: 'fr'
  })
  .help().argv;
```